# Object is being overridden

Tags: java, object

I have Java problem - I have object like that:
GUIItemBuilder

And when I try to use it:

```
GUIItemBuilder item2 = new GUIItemBuilder(is,"def", "123", new ArrayList<>()); //THIS ONE
//A PLACE
GUIItemBuilder item = new GUIItemBuilder(is, "abc", "456", new ArrayList<>());
//B PLACE
```

and get "item2" name with getItemStack() function, it returns me value from "item" - like "item2" is being overrided, but it shouldn't. What happened? 
I tried to debug that by sending item2 function in "A" place - it was good, but when I did it in "B" place - as I said before - it looks like it's being overrided.

GUIBuilder: https://hastebin.com/wibosudibu.java
GUIItemBuilder: https://hastebin.com/ahoxayumij.cpp
Command:

Comment: The code passes the same `is` instance into the constructor of both `item2` and `item` so both refer to the same object.  Perhaps the constructor needs to make a defensive copy?

Comment: _"get "item2" name with getItemStack() function"_ --  Shouldn't you be using `getItemName()` to get the name, and *not* `getItemStack()`?  Both items have the same ItemStack, because you're passing the same `is` variable to both of their constructors.  But since ItemStack is not the name, I suspect that you're just (or also) calling the wrong method here.

Comment: Post your full code. You already knows it works well when no other codes mixed in.

Answer (score 0):

To add full detail to Andrew's comment, what you're doing here is reusing the same object twice.  Here's a simplified example.

```
public static class ItemStack {
    public String displayName;
}

public static class Item {
    private ItemStack stack;
    private String name;
     public Item(ItemStack s, String name) {
         this.stack = s;
         this.stack.displayName = name;
         this.name = name;
     }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    ItemStack stack = new ItemStack();
    stack.displayName = "Start";
    System.out.println(stack.displayName);
    Item a = new Item(stack, "a");
    System.out.println(stack.displayName);
    Item b = new Item(stack, "b");
    System.out.println(stack.displayName);
}
```

This will output

```
Start
a
b
```

When you pass `stack` to the constructor, it doesn't make a new copy of it, just uses a reference to it.  So any change made to one happens in all of them since each of those variables is actually pointing to the same object in memory.  If you want these to all be separate copies, you need to copy the contents into a new object.  For my example, adding a copy constructor

```
public ItemStack(ItemStack a) {
        this.displayName = a.displayName;
    }
```

to `ItemStack` and changing the first line in the `Item` constructor

```
this.stack = new ItemStack(s);
```

will give an output of

```
Start
Start
Start
```